# Save multiple images quickly in iOS 6 (custom album)

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I'm writing an application that will take several images from URL's, turn them into a UIImage and then add them to the photo library and then to the custom album. I don't believe its possible to add them to a custom album without having them in the Camera Roll, so I'm accepting it as impossible (but it would be ideal if this is possible).

My problem is that I'm using the code from [this site](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/) and it does work, but once it's dealing with larger photos it returns a few as 'Write Busy'. I have successfully got them all to save if I copy the function inside its own completion code and then again inside the next one and so on until 6 (the most I saw it take was 3-4 but I don't know the size of the images and I could get some really big ones) - this has lead to the problem that they weren't all included in the custom album as they error'd at this stage too and there was no block in place to get it to repeat.

I understand that the actual image saving is moved to a background thread (although I don't specifically set this) as my code returns as all done before errors start appearing, but ideally I need to queue up images to be saved on a single background thread so they happen synchronously but do not freeze the UI.

My code looks like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:singleImage]]];
    [self.library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"Test Album" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }
    }];
```

I've removed the repetition of the code otherwise the code sample would be very long! It was previously where the NSLog code existed.

For my test sample I am dealing with 25 images, but this could easily be 200 or so, and could be very high resolution, so I need something that's able to reliably do this over and over again without missing several images.

thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make it work by stripping out the save image code and moving it into its own function which calls itself recursively on an array on objects, if it fails it re-parses the same image back into the function until it works successfully and will display 'Done' when complete. Because I'm using the completedBlock: from the function to complete the loop, its only running one file save per run.

This is the code I used recursively:

```
- (void)saveImage {

if(self.thisImage)
{
    [self.library saveImage:self.thisImage toAlbum:@"Test Album" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil) {
            [self saveImage];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.imageData removeObject:self.singleImageData];
            NSLog(@"Success!");
            self.singleImageData = [self.imageData lastObject];
            self.thisImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.singleImageData]]];
            [self saveImage];
        }
    }];
}
else
{
    self.singleImageData = nil;
    self.thisImage = nil;
    self.imageData = nil;
    self.images = nil;
    NSLog(@"Done!");
}
```

}

To set this up, I originally used an array of UIImages's but this used a lot of memory and was very slow (I was testing up to 400 photos). I found a much better way to do it was to store an NSMutableArray of URL's as NSString's and then perform the NSData GET within the function.

The following code is what sets up the NSMutableArray with data and then calls the function. It also sets the first UIImage into memory and stores it under self.thisImage:

```
NSEnumerator *e = [allDataArray objectEnumerator];
NSDictionary *object;

while (object = [e nextObject]) {
    NSArray *imagesArray = [object objectForKey:@"images"];
    NSString *singleImage = [[imagesArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"source"];
    [self.imageData addObject:singleImage];
}

self.singleImageData = [self.imageData lastObject];
self.thisImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.singleImageData]]];
[self saveImage];
```

This means the rest of the getters for UIImage can be contained in the function and the single instance of UIImage can be monitored. I also log the raw URL into self.singleImageData so that I can remove the correct elements from the array to stop duplication.

These are the variables I used:

```
self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.thisImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
self.imageData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.singleImageData = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

This answer should work for anyone using http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/ for iOS 6 (tested on iOS 6.1) and should result in all pictures being saved correctly and without errors.

Answer (score 0):

If saveImage:toAlbum:withCompletionBlock it's using dispatch_async i fear that for i/o operations too many threads are spawned: each write task you trigger is blocked by the previous one (bacause is still doing I/O on the same queue), so gcd will create a new thread (usually dispatch_async on the global_queue is optimized by gcd by using an optimized number of threads).

You should either use semaphores to limit the write operation to a fixed number at the same time or use dispatch_io_ functions that are available from iOS 5 if i'm not mistaken.
There are plenty example on how to do this with both methods.

some on the fly code for giving an idea:

```
 dispatch_semaphore_t aSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(4);
 dispatch_queue_t ioQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.customqueue", NULL);

 // dispatch the following block to the ioQueue
 // ( for loop with all images )
 dispatch_semaphore_wait(aSemaphore , DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
 [self.library saveImage:image 
                 toAlbum:@"Test Album"
     withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error){
          dispatch_semaphore_signal(aSemaphore);
     }];
```

so every time you will have maximum 4 saveImage:toAlbum, as soon as one completes another one will start.
you have to create a custom queue, like above (the ioQueue) where to dispatch the code that does the for loop on the images, so when the semaphore is waiting the main thread is not blocked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I am not familiar with semaphores, but I'll do some reading into them as they look quite useful. I only started a week ago!

Comment: this is a good link i think http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-09-25-gcd-practicum.html but it's a bit advanced.